# Print button on a page which prints another page

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page called order where I have Print button. On click to the print I want to print another page called print_this which is there.

```
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'Place order', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Print', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

So say the button is at this URL: `http://localhost:3000/o/p` so on the click of print I want to open `http://localhost:3000/orders/1` , i.e directly print should pop up.

Please help.

Comment: Pass some parameter to final page like `http://localhost:3000/orders/1?print=true` and in javascript trigger `window.print()` function

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: quite difficult to understand, are you trying to get which submit button is clicked by user?

Comment: On click of print button which is on "this" page, I want to print "this_page".
I hope this doesn't confuse you more

Comment: Make hyperlink with print button which will open `http://localhost:3000/orders/1?print=true` page and in `orders` page write js code to check passed parameters. if `print=true` parameter is present in URL trigger `window.print()`

Comment: thanks deadlock, It works..
If you can add the comment as an answer, I will accept as an answer.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make hyperlink with print button which will open `http://localhost:3000/orders/1?print=true` page and in `orders` page write js code to check passed parameters. if `print=true` parameter is present in URL trigger `window.print()`

Comment: Hey, thanks. I did the same way but like 6 months back. Thanks

Comment: I just read comments that my solution helped you to solve problem. So I posted this as an answer